# Returning StringIO object

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-object

I have the following python code:

```py
def parse_object(object):
    data = object.read()
    do_other_stuff(data)
```

```py
def get_object():
    content = "abc"
    try:
        object = StringIO()
        object.write(content)
        return object
    finally:
        object.close()
```

```py
def main():
    object = get_object()
    parse_object(object)
```

parse_object gets a file object or a StringIO instance, but obviously the StringIO object is getting closed as soon as get_object ends.
Is there a way of closing the object within get_object after it is being used?
parse_object cannot be altered because it is in a builtin library which I rather not change, get_object is in my code

Comment: There is no need to close the `StringIO` instance. Just return it and drop the `try`/`finally`.

Comment: But I would like to prevent a memory leak, especially if I plan on doing it hundreds of times...

Comment: "Closing" a resource does not free the memory it occupies. Python is garbage collected. When a variable is no longer used, the space it occupies will be freed automatically. For entirely internal resources like `StringIO` objects you create for your own use, this mechanism works perfectly well and you don't need to do anything special. Just create them, use them, and don't worry too much. For external resources (like database connections and files) manual closing can become necessary so you don't occupy them longer than needed. But even here, "closing" is not the same as "feeing memory".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python automatic closing is a typical work of context manager. See reference at https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


def parse_object(object):
    data = object.read()
    do_other_stuff(data)

@contextmanager
def get_object():
    content = "abc"
    try:
        object = StringIO()
        object.write(content)
        yield object
    finally:
        object.close()

def main():
    with get_object() as object:
        parse_object(object)
```

Comment: ...it's just not necessary in this case. Nothing is won by closing a `StringIO` object.